# How to change the value of a column (which contains NA values) by the sum of 2 other colums which also contain NA values in R?

Tags: r

```
#reproducible example data
data <- read.table(text = "Column_A Column_B Column_C
NA 0 2
7 5 2
2 NA 1", header = TRUE)
#   Column_A Column_B Column_C
# 1       NA        0        2
# 2        7        5        2
# 3        2       NA        1
```

Changing the values of A by the sum of B and C

I have tried this:

```
data$Column_A = replace(data$Column_A, is.na(data$Column_A), data$Column_B + data$Column_C)
data$Column_B = replace(data$Column_B, is.na(data$Column_B), data$Column_A - data$Column_C)
data$Column_C = replace(data$Column_C, is.na(data$Column_C), data$Column_A - data$Column_B)
```

But this didn't work, I thought of making a for-loop but I didn't know how to start doing that.

Is there anyone that could help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`dplyr::coalesce()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html):

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(
    ColumnA = coalesce(ColumnA, ColumnB + ColumnC),
    ColumnB = coalesce(ColumnB, ColumnA - ColumnC),
    ColumnC = coalesce(ColumnC, ColumnA - ColumnB)
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       2       0       2
2       7       5       2
3       2       1       1
```

Comment: But the last row should be 2 1 1 because B + C = A

Comment: @MikoM is it true for every row? B + C = A?

Comment: @MikoM, sorry, I missed that — see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes it is for every row, thank you for your effort!